# gradle substitute string of another module

Tags: android, xml, gradle, buildconfig

In my build.config I can add some text markers which get replaced in xml:

```
resValue "string", "id", text
```

this works within one android module. 
Now I want to substitute text for a xml file in one module with a build.config of another module. How is this possible?